# Get all words in sequence form in sentence

Tags: php, regex

For example I have sentence like below

```
VA Trance Pro-Motion [PartI](December 2014)<4CD>{1337x} TheDanceCube.
```

I want to store result into array in following format

```
[1]->VA
[2]->Trance
[3]->Pro-Motion
[4]->[PartI]
[5]->(December 2014) 
[6]-><4CD>
.
.
and so on till full sentence
```

Any idea how it can be achieved ?

I tried something like below

```
$final = str_explode(' ',$string);
```

But it wont work for things inside brackets..I think its possible only via regex ?or any other easy functions available ?

Comment: for the one who did -1 , I have edited question.

Comment: Is the format of the sentence always the same?

Comment: no , it vary ...generally should consider any bracket as seperate word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work:

```
((?:\w|-)+|(?:\([^\)]+\))|(?:\{[^\}]+\})|(?:\[[^\]]+\])|(?:<[^>]+>))
```

with a global flag `g` (`preg_match_all()` in PHP)

see example here: https://regex101.com/r/oN3vS2/1

**How it works:**

This wwould capture all words with `-` also (but ignoring brackets)

```
((?:\w|-)+?)
```

The rest are blocks for each type of brackets, like this for `()`:

```
(?:\([^\)]+\))
```

**For utf-16 characters use:**

```
preg_match_all('/((?:\w|-)+|(?:\([^\)]+\))|(?:\{[^\}]+\})|(?:\[[^\]]+\])|(?:<[^>]+>))/u', $phrase, $results);
```

**Note:**

This code **won't** stop at the end of the sentence, but there are probably better ways than this regex, to do that (like `split('.', $phrase)` or `explode('.', $phrase)` before )

Comment: there is no global for php.I tried preg_match_all and its working.....but the above code not working for strings like  Вася Обломов

Comment: `u` flag should help OR use `[\p{L}\p{N}_]` instead of `\w`

Comment: I get PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 5 error

Comment: `u` is a flag - use it after closing `/` (I updated my answer with full example)